# Flutter failed directory

Tags: flutter

Everyone. How are you?

I'm installing Flutter using a M1 macbook Air, but when I installing it gave me an error that "Flutter failed to create a directory" but I followed what it showed me in flutter documentation like adding the path and stuff.

Here's the error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VX3X.png)

Regards,

Abelaash Giritharan

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permissions issue with your account. Does your account have admin access? If you don't try running the command as sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try that
`sudo chown -R <yourusername> .config`
or check these links:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96519
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92961